# How to change url so a file is automatically loaded inside a div?

Tags: jquery

Clicking on a div inside a sidebar I load a specific file inside a div.

```
<div id="menuLeft">
<div id="file01">File 01</div>
<div id="file02">File 02</div>
<div id="file03">File 03</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$("#menuLeft div").click(function () {
var id = "chapters/" + $(this).attr('id') + ".php";
$('#divRight').load(id);
});
```

This all works, but url is always the same - for example `www.something.com`

What I need by clicking on the sidebar is to get something like `www.something.com#file01`, or any other content, so when this url is entered in another window, `file01` is automatically loaded inside `divRight`.

Any help?

Comment: When the page loads, check for `location.hash`.  If it's set, then strip off the leading `#` and call `.load()`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, thanks, I will try. Just a question: If I have another div with the same procedure, can I have two or three hashs inside url ?

Comment: You can make the hash value whatever you want.  For example you can do `#file01,file02`.  Then just remove the `#` and use `.split(',')`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, thanks once more. Solved, probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to do.

First, you need to change the hash:

```
document.location.hash = "file01";
```

And then secondly on page load, check the hash and load the appropriate file.

However, what's probably better is using [HistoryAPI](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) or a similar implementation. For instance [HistoryJS](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) will allow you to create states, so that people can press Back and Forward in the browser and switch between these pages.